# Excel Auto Increment based on adjacent cells

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a VBA macro that will auto number all cells in column 'A' to a single decimal place, if and only if they have a value in column 'B'.  Every time there is a row that does not have a value in column 'B', column 'A' should re-start numbering at the next integer.

IE:

```
|COLUMN A | COLUMN B|
|:-------:|:-------:|
|  1.1    |  TEXT   |
|  1.2    |  TEXT   |
|  1.3    |  TEXT   |
|  1.4    |  TEXT   |
|  1.5    |  TEXT   |
|         | *NO TEXT* |
|  2.1    |  TEXT   |
|  2.2    |  TEXT   |
|  2.3    |  TEXT   |
|         | *NO TEXT* |
|  3.1    |  TEXT   |
|  3.2    |  TEXT   |
|  3.3    |  TEXT   |
|  3.4    |  TEXT   |
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds very cool, but SO isn't a code-writing service. Please see [ask] and [mcve], and try to formulate a *specific* question about a *specific* programming issue you're facing.

Comment: It can be done with a simple formula, `=IF(B21<>"",IF(B20="",INT(A19)+1.1,A20+0.1),"")` then copy down.  This is simplistic, and may need some changes if A19:B20 are not empty cells.

Comment: You don't bother to reply to the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is pretty self-explanatory, but post up if anything confuses you:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub numberCells()

    Dim totalRows As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim baseNumber As Long
    Dim count As Integer

    totalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count

    baseNumber = 1
    i = 2

    Do While i <= totalRows

        If Range("B" & i).Value <> "" Then

            count = count + 1
            Range("A" & i).Value = baseNumber & "." & count

        Else

            baseNumber = baseNumber + 1
            count = 0

        End If

        i = i + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: That did it!  I modified it slightly to not repeat numbers if there are more than 10 rows in a single section:Do While i <= totalRows
        If Range(typeColumn & i).Value <> "" Then
            If count >= 9 Then
                baseNumber = baseNumber + 1
                count = 1
                Range("A" & i).Value = baseNumber & "." & count
            Else
                count = count + 1
                Range("A" & i).Value = baseNumber & "." & count
            End If
        Else
            baseNumber = baseNumber + 1
            count = 0
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

Answer (score 0):

I like using `.Areas`,

[image]

Here's my version

```
Sub Do_It_Good()
    Dim RangeArea As Range, c As Range, LstRw As Long, sh As Worksheet, Rng As Range


    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set Rng = .Range("B2:B" & LstRw)

        y = 0

        For Each RangeArea In Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Areas
            y = y + 1
            x = 0

            For Each c In RangeArea.Cells
                c.Offset(, -1) = y & "." & 1 + x
                x = x + 1
            Next c

        Next RangeArea
    End With

End Sub
```